# Display text as popup

Tags: popup

I want to show "Please go back and check the I am not a robot box" in pop up,how can I do it? this is in html page

This will display if captcha is not selected ( google captcha).

```
 if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
      $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    }
    if(!$captcha){
      echo '<h2>Please go back and check the I am not a robot box.</h2>';
      exit;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest that you assume that if the "I am not a robot" thingie is not checked, it probably means the user **is** a robot. You should probably then redirect to some random web-site, such as msn.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the javascript alert box.

alert("Please go back and check the I am not a robot box.");

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

If you'd rather have something nicer (And it's probably a better idea as an Alert box can be interpreted as an error) I'd go with a jquery popup, dialog works well, here's a quick look at how it's implemented in the code:

```
$('#dialog-confirm').dialog("option", "buttons", [
        {
          text: 'Please go back and check the I am not a robot box.',
          click: function () { $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("close"); }
        }
]); //end buttons

$('#dialog-confirm').dialog("open");
```

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/